# Android photo capturing and showing from gallery

Tags: android

I'm having some problems with my android app. My idea is to see the photo I take using my app or to choose from my custom gallery and see it. First of all I'm having problems with viewing the image, in particular I catch a null pointer exception when i try to see the bitmap, then when I try to see a photo from gallery the app crashes maybe because I'm unable to make the directory refresh properly.
Here is my code:

`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fotocamera);
    b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSelectPhoto);
    //viewImage=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.viewImage);
    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            selectImage();
        }
    });
}



@Override

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds options to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.fotocamera, menu);
    return true;
}

private void selectImage() {
    final CharSequence[] options = { "Scatta una foto", "Scegli una foto dalla galleria", "Carica una foto", "Annulla" };
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FotocameraActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Cosa vuoi fare?");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if (options[item].equals("Scatta una foto")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                photoDirectory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ File.separator + "FTRRome");
                File camdir = new File("/external/images/media");
                boolean res = camdir.exists();
                System.out.println(res);
                if(!photoDirectory.exists()) {
                    photoDirectory.mkdirs();
                }
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss");
                String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
                File f = new File(photoDirectory, (currentDateandTime+".jpg"));
                lastPhoto = f;
                intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(f));
                System.out.println(photoDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
                System.out.println(lastPhoto.getAbsolutePath());
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }

            /*else if (options[item].equals("Scegli una foto dalla galleria")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                System.out.println(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                System.out.println(photoDirectory);

                //sendBroadcast (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/FTRRome/")));
            }
            else if (options[item].equals("Carica una foto dalla galleria")) {
                Intent intent = new   Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                System.out.println(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
                System.out.println(photoDirectory);
                sendBroadcast (new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,Uri.parse("file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/FTRRome/")));
                startActivityForResult(intent, 3);
            }

            else if (options[item].equals("Annulla")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
            */
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        System.out.println("Questo è il codice di risultato: " + requestCode);
        if (requestCode == 1) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Creo bitmap");
                Bitmap bitmap;
                System.out.println("Setto bitmap options");
                BitmapFactory.Options bitmapOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                System.out.println("Setto decodifica");
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(lastPhoto.getAbsolutePath(),bitmapOptions);
                System.out.println("Chiedo visualizzazione");
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                OutputStream outFile = null;
                try {
                    outFile = new FileOutputStream(lastPhoto);
                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, outFile);
                    outFile.flush();
                    outFile.close();
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        /*else if (requestCode == 2) {
            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            System.out.println(selectedImage.getPath());
            String[] filePath =  { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
            Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
            c.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
            String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
            c.close();
            Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Log.w("path of image from gallery: ", picturePath+"");
            viewImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        }
        */
    }
}
```

}`